# PHP - Convert RegExp to string

Tags: php, regex

I tried several times to find a solution without an idea of how to approach it.

I want to convert this string: **'^3816[4-6].*$'**; 
Into this: **'38164, 38165, 38166'**;

In other words I want to genarate all the possible options of a given string: **'XXXX[2-7]'**; 
So the output should be: **'XXXX2, XXXX3, XXXX4, XXXX5, XXXX6, XXXX7'**;

please help me to solve this issue if anyone know how to accomplish it.

Comment: There's not really a clean way to do this without at least partially building a regex interpreter, and even then... the `.*` matches an indefinitely long string of any character, so trying to figure out every possible combination with that is impossible.

Comment: My question is why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you give us more informations on the different transformations you want to be able to make and their syntax ?

Comment: Is this what you're after: `/^(3816[4-6],?){3}$/`. It's a regex that matches _38164,38165,38166_. You can replace the `{3}` with `+` to allow more repeated matches of the basic pattern

Comment: Another example for the action is: the string: 'XXXX[1-6]'; To: 'XXXX1,XXXX2,XXXX3,XXXX4,XXXX5,XXXX6,';

Comment: I need to get all the combinations of the given regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RegExp ;)

```
<?php

$string_pattern =  '^3816[4-6].*$';
$pattern = '/^\^(.*)\[(.)-(.)\](.*)\$$/';
preg_match($pattern, $string_pattern, $matches);

for ($i = $matches[2]; $i <=$matches[3] ; $i++) echo $matches[1].$i.$matches[4]."\n";

?>
```

The question is: what really contains `$matches[4]`?

Comment: WOW toto21 you have just solved my problem! Thank you!